# MVC 4 ajax upload file .copyto leaving file open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, filestream

I am using MVC 4, C# 4 and ajax to post a form with a file input on it. All is working fine except that I can see the file being written to the server, but it seems to be locked until I manually refresh the page. So it seems as though something is locking it, i.e. did I not close something, etc during the write?

In my controller, I capture the file InputStream and pass it to the services layer.

Controller capture code:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                file = Request.Files[0]; //Uploaded file
                fileName = file.FileName;
                mimeType = file.ContentType;
                fileContent = file.InputStream;
            }
```

Services Layer code, where fileStream is of type Stream and was passed in from file.InputStream in the controller.

```
//Write file to disk path
                fileStream.CopyTo(File.OpenWrite(diskPath + newfileName));
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this in using statements works and doesn't lock the file

```
using (var output = File.OpenWrite(diskPath + newfileName))
                {
                    using (var input = fileStream)
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(output);
                    }
                }
```